# Rails sync ranges inside of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Currently I have a problem with synchronizing time periods in Ruby on Rails.

I have 2 arrays of none to n hashes that I need to compare and then have synchronous time periods in a "result" array.

As an example:

```
time_periods_a = [
  { start_date: '01/10/2021', end_date: '31/10/2021',
    additional_attribute: 5 },
  { start_date: '01/11/2021', end_date: '30/11/2021',
    additional_attribute: 10 }
]

time_periods_b = [
  { start_date: '01/10/2021', end_date: '31/12/2021',
    additional_attribute: 20 }
```

The result should be:

```
[
  { start_date: '01/10/2021', end_date: '31/10/2021',
    additional_attribute_a: 5, additional_attribute_b: 20 },
  { start_date: '01/11/2021', end_date: '30/11/2021',
    additional_attribute_a: 10, additional_attribute_b: 20 },
  { start_date: '01/12/2021', end_date: '31/12/2021',
    additional_attribute_a: 0, additional_attribute_b: 20 }
]
```

Maybe you have a simple solution for this, I despair already for 2 days.

EDIT:

Since i didnt explained the Question well enough, here is an edit for it:

The two arrays may contain hashes that overlap. Generally, these must then be split into several periods.

Maybe another example, a little shorter but more complicated.

`time_periods_a: [1 - 2, 3 - 6, 7 - 9]`
`time_periods_b: [ 2-5, 6-9]`

This needs to result in: `[1-1, 2-2, 3-5, 6-6, 7-9]`

This numbers are just the month index, because the start_date is at the begin of the month every time and the end_date at the end of the month.

It's not required that both arrays contains the same periods, but its possible.
That is why i added the additional attribute.
If one time period is covered in 1 array but not in the other, then i need to add this period with just an `additional_attribute: 0`

EDIT #2 CODE I USED BEFORE

```
  def format_date_ranges(example_model)
    first_array = example_model.first_array
    second_array = example_model.second_array
    return first_array.map { |hash| hash.merge('additional_attribute_b' => hash['additional_attribute'], 'additional_attribute_b' => 0) } if second_array.blank?
    return first_array.map { |hash| hash.merge('additional_attribute_a' => hash['additional_attribute'], 'additional_attribute_b' => 0) } if second_array.blank?

    iterate_count = [first_array.size, second_array.size].max
    result_array = []
    iterate_count.times do |index|
      relevant_first_hash = first_hash[index]
      releveant_second_hash = second_hash[index]
      if relevant_first_hash.nil?
        result_array << result_hash(0,
                                    releveant_second_hash['additional_attribute'],
                                    releveant_second_hash['start_date'],
                                    releveant_second_hash['end_date'],
                                    '')
        next
      end

      if relevant_second_hash.nil?
        result_array << result_hash(relevant_first_hash['additional_attribute'],
                                    0,
                                    relevant_first_hash['start_date'],
                                    relevant_first_hash['end_date'],
                                    relevant_first_hash['interval'])
        next
      end

      first_start_date = relevant_first_hash['start_date'].to_date
      first_end_date = relevant_first_hash['end_date'].to_date
      second_start_date = relevant_second_hash['start_date'].to_date
      second_end_date = relevant_second_hash['end_date'].to_date

      if first_start_date == second_start_date
        start_date = second_start_date
      else
        start_date = [first_start_date, second_start_date].min
        end_date = [first_start_date, second_start_date].max - 1.day
        result_array << result_hash(relevant_first_hash['additional_attribute'],
                                    relevant_second_hash['additional_attribute'],
                                    start_date,
                                    end_date,
                                    relevant_first_hash['interval'])
        start_date = [first_start_date, second_start_date].max
      end
      if first_end_date == second_end_date
        end_date = second_end_date
      else
        end_date = [first_end_date, second_end_date].min
        result_array << result_hash(relevant_first_hash['additional_attribute'],
                                    relevant_second_hash['additional_attribute'],
                                    start_date,
                                    end_date,
                                    relevant_first_hash['interval'])
        start_date = end_date + 1.day
        end_date = [first_end_date, second_end_date].max
      end
      result_array << result_hash(relevant_first_hash['additional_attribute'],
                                  relevant_second_hash['additional_attribute'],
                                  start_date,
                                  end_date,
                                  relevant_first_hash['interval'])
    end
    result_array
  end

  def result_hash(additional_attribute_a, additional_attribute_b, start_date, end_date, interval)
    { additional_attribute_a: additional_attribute_a, additional_attribute_b: additional_attribute_b, start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date, interval: interval }
  end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronous time periods"? Because you can get your desired result by doing a simple `time_periods_a + time_periods_b` (assuming you have a typo in your definition of `time_periods_b` with the `start_date` being supposed to be `01/12/2021`). But I suspect that apparent typo is actually where your problem lies and that you have a more complex requirement that you've not explained.

Comment: @JohnP Maybe i didn't explained the problem as much as expected.
There is no typo in the `start_date` .
The two arrays may contain hashes that overlap. Generally, these must then be split into several periods. 

Maybe another example, a little shorter but more complicated. 

time_periods_a: `[1 - 2, 3 - 6, 7 - 9]`
time_periods_b: `[ 2-5, 6-9]`

This needs to result in: 
`[1-1, 2-2, 3-5, 6-6, 7-9]`

This numbers are just the month index, because the start_date is at the begin of the month every time and the end_date at the end of the month. 
Maybe its now a little bit clearer.

Comment: So what do you mean by "synchronous time periods" then, as I asked? I've literally no idea what problem you are trying to solve here. (Especially seeing as there's definitely a problem in one of those date ranges because it refers to the end date `31/11/2021`, which doesn't exist.)

Comment: @JohnP edited the comment.

Comment: It's not required that both arrays contains the same periods, but its possible. 
That is why i added the additional attribute. If one time period is covered in 1 array but not in the other, then i need to add this period with just an `additional_attribute: 0`

Comment: I think I can just about grasp what you want now. You start with two sets of date ranges, and want an output that splits these into a unique set of date ranges, such that each range in the output represents a discrete period in either or both of the inputs. Overlapping ranges (i.e. dates present in both inputs) should be split up so that the unique ranges in the output span the ranges in all the inputs. In which case, you need a fairly complex method that checks each input date range against each other range using e.g. `overlaps?` and splits them if they do overlap.

Comment: (You should probably update the question, once you have a clear statement of your problem. Sharing the code you've tried would help, too!)

Comment: @JohnP Yea i guess thats a good conclusion of the Problem. My english is not the best, tried to sum it up as good as i can.

I will share my code later on, its almost done i guess. Just one thing that i dont mind and it destroys the whole result.

Comment: Heh - well that sounds promising. If you have mostly-working code then there's a decent chance someone will be able to fix it!

Comment: Bobo, when asked for clarification it is preferable to edit your question rather than to elaborate in comments. Readers should not be expected to read through all the comments to understand what you are trying to do. Questions should be self-contained. Clarification is still required. Note that I made a correction to your data, as "30 days hath November". :-)

Comment: @JohnP i edited my Question. I will try the answer you gave me, thank you for that explanation!

Comment: @CarySwoveland i edited my question and somehow i can just mention 1 person, so here is an additional comment just for that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way around the complexity of the problem short of re-thinking your data structures, something you might consider doing. I have tried to explain most of the steps below but you may have to run the code with some `puts` statements salted in to obtain a thorough understanding.

I have generalized the problem into one having any number of arrays of hashes, which actually simplifies the code.

**Given data and generalization**

```
a = [
  { start_date: '01/10/2021', end_date: '31/10/2021',
    additional_attribute: 5 },
  { start_date: '01/11/2021', end_date: '30/11/2021',
    additional_attribute: 10 }
]

b = [
  { start_date: '01/10/2021', end_date: '31/12/2021',
    additional_attribute: 20 }
]
```

Let

```
array = [a, b]
  #=> [[{:start_date=>"01/10/2021", :end_date=>"31/10/2021",
  #      :additional_attribute=>5},
  #     {:start_date=>"01/11/2021", :end_date=>"30/11/2021",
  #      :additional_attribute=>10}],
  #    [{:start_date=>"01/10/2021", :end_date=>"31/12/2021",
  #      :additional_attribute=>20}]]
```

**Create two helper methods**

```
def date_str_to_date(date_str)
  DateTime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%Y')
end
```

```
def date_to_date_str(date_time)
    date_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
end
```

For example:

```
date_str_to_date('01/10/2021')
  #=> #<DateTime: 2021-10-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459489j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date_to_date_str(date_str_to_date('31/12/2021'))
  #=> "31/12/2021"
```

See [DateTime::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime)

**​Convert `array` to an array of hashes**

```
arr =
  array.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(ar,i),a2|
    ar.each do |h|
      a2 << h.merge(start_date: date_str_to_date(h[:start_date]),
                    end_date: date_str_to_date(h[:end_date]), idx: i)
    end
  end
  #=> [{:start_date=>#<DateTime: 2021-10-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459489j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     :end_date=>#<DateTime: 2021-10-31T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459519j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     :additional_attribute=>5, :idx=>0},
  #    {:start_date=>#<DateTime: 2021-11-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459520j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     :end_date=>#<DateTime: 2021-11-30T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459549j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     :additional_attribute=>10, :idx=>0},
  #    {:start_date=>#<DateTime: 2021-10-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459489j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     :end_date=>#<DateTime: 2021-12-31T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459580j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     :additional_attribute=>20, :idx=>1}]
```

Note that each of the hashes in `a` and `b` are mapped to a hash in `arr` and those from `a` have `:idx => 0` and those from `b` have `:idx => 1`.

**Compute the earliest start date and latest end date**

```
start, finish = arr.flat_map { |h| [h[:start_date], h[:end_date]] }.minmax
  #=> [#<DateTime: 2021-10-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459489j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #    #<DateTime: 2021-12-31T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459580j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

so

```
start
  #=> #<DateTime: 2021-10-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459489j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
finish
  #=> #<DateTime: 2021-12-31T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459580j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Array#minmax](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-minmax).

**For each date between `start` and `finish` construct a set of indices of elements of `arr` whose ranges include the given date**

```
require 'set'
```

```
coverage_by_date = (start..finish).map do |date|
  [date,
   arr.each_index.select do |i|
    (arr[i][:start_date]..arr[i][:end_date]).cover?(date)
   end.to_set
  ]
end
  #=> [[#<DateTime: 2021-10-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459489j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Set: {0, 2}>],
  #    [#<DateTime: 2021-10-02T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459490j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Set: {0, 2}>],
  #    ...
  #    [#<DateTime: 2021-10-31T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459519j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Set: {0, 2}>],
  #    [#<DateTime: 2021-11-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459520j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Set: {1, 2}>],
  #    ...
  #    [#<DateTime: 2021-11-30T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459549j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Set: {1, 2}>],
  #    [#<DateTime: 2021-12-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459550j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Set: {2}>],
  #    ...
  #    [#<DateTime: 2021-12-31T00:00:00+00:00 ((2459580j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>, #<Set: {2}>]]
```

**Lastly, remove dates with empty coverage sets and slice resulting array of dates into ranges with equal coverage sets, then map to the desired hashes**

```
coverage_by_date.reject { |_,set| set.empty? }
                .slice_when { |(_,set1),(_,set2)| set1 != set2 }
                .map do |ar|
                   attributes = ar.first
                                  .last
                                  .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |i,h|
                                     g = arr[i] 
                                     h[g[:idx]] = g[:additional_attribute]
                                   end.values_at(*0..array.size-1)
                   { start_date: date_to_date_str(ar.first.first),
                     end_date: date_to_date_str(ar.last.first), 
                     attributes: attributes }                       
                 end
  #=> [{:start_date=>"01/10/2021", :end_date=>"31/10/2021", :attributes=>[5, 20]},
  #    {:start_date=>"01/11/2021", :end_date=>"30/11/2021", :attributes=>[10, 20]},
  #    {:start_date=>"01/12/2021", :end_date=>"31/12/2021", :attributes=>[0, 20]}]
```

When (for example)

```
ar.first.last
  #=> #<Set: {0, 2}>
```

we find that

```
attributes
  #=> [5, 20]
```

Note:

```
coverage_by_date.reject { |_,set| set.empty? }
                .slice_when { |(_,set1),(_,set2)| set1 != set2 }
                .map do |ar|
                   { start_date: date_to_date_str(ar.first.first),
                     end_date: date_to_date_str(ar.last.first),
                     set: ar.first.last }
                 end
  #=> [{:start_date=>"01/10/2021", :end_date=>"31/10/2021", :set=>#<Set: {0, 2}>},
  #    {:start_date=>"01/11/2021", :end_date=>"30/11/2021", :set=>#<Set: {1, 2}>},
  #    {:start_date=>"01/12/2021", :end_date=>"31/12/2021", :set=>#<Set: {2}>}]
```

See [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument (the *default value*) and no block, and [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at).

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for!